# Type annotation for mutable dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a class `MyClass` with 2 methods. The methods change an attribute `dic` of type `dict[str, A]` by adding objects of subtypes `B` and `C`:

```py
class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    def method_B(self): ...

class C(A):
    def method_C(self): ...

class MyClass:
    dic: dict[str, A] = {}
    
    def add_B_obj(self, name: str):
        self.dic[name] = B()

    def add_C_obj(self, name: str):
        self.dic[name] = C()
```

I would like to access the methods of the objects inside the dictionary after their creation, for instance, using Pylance.

For that, the following snippet doesn't work (see the warning):

```py
m = MyClass()
m.add_B_obj('B_obj')

m.dic['B_obj'].method_B() # Warning: Cannot access member "method_B" for type "A"
```

To solve that, I tried to use `typing.cast`.
I'm not interested in objects of type `C`, so I used `cast` to force `m.dic` to be of type `dict[str,B]`.
That allows me to access the method, but there was a new warning:

```py
from typing import cast

m = MyClass()
m.add_B_obj('B_obj')

m.dic = cast(dict[str,B],m.dic['B_obj']) # WARNING

m.dic['B_obj'].method_B # now pylance shows me the method, but there is a new warning
```

The new warning is:

```
 Cannot assign member "dic" for type "MyClass"
  "dict[str, B]" is incompatible with "dict[str, A]"
    TypeVar "_VT@dict" is invariant
      "B" is incompatible with "A"
```

How do I solve this new warning?

Answer (score 1):

### Type safety for `dict` values

All values in a dictionary are treated the same by a static type checker.

If you tell the type checker that a dictionary `dic` can contain values of both type `A` and type `B`, but only `B` has the method `method_B`, then it logically follows that *not all* of the values in `dic` have `method_B`.

There is no way for the type checker to know for certain, if *some particular* value from `dic` has `method_B`.

In your example, `B` is a subtype of `A`, so by annotating `dic` with `dict[str, A]` you allow both `A` and `B` to be values in that dictionary. You could make the error more explicit, if you annotate it with `dict[str, Union[A, B]]` (which is equivalent from a typing perspective); then `mypy` for example will correctly tell you:

```
error: Item "A" of "Union[A, B]" has no attribute "method_B"
```

Highlighting the fact that `B` has it, but that is not enough for type safety.

The only way to *assure* the type checker that a *specific* value in the dictionary has `method_B` is to explicitly assert it for *that specific* key:

```py
...
assert isinstance(m.dic['B_obj'], B)
m.dic['B_obj'].method_B()
```

Even this doesn't satisfy *every* type checker. `mypy` is happy, but the PyCharm built-in type checker still marks that last call saying:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'method_B' for class 'A'
```

The other option is to use [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) properly with an intermediary variable:

```py
b = cast(B, m.dic['B_obj'])
b.method_B()
```

This should satisfy *all* type checkers.

I hope my explanation makes it clear that there is no other way around this.

---

### Type (in)variance

As for the variance issue after `cast`-ing, your attempt is wrong for two reasons.

Firstly, you are only passing the *value* corresponding to the key `'B_obj'` to `cast`, not the entire `dic`. Which means that after your assignment

```py
m.dic = cast(dict[str, B], m.dic['B_obj'])
```

The attribute `dic` of object `m` is just that value, i.e. an instance of class `B`. This would lead to an TypeError, as soon as you tried this:

```py
m.dic['B_obj']
```

Because `B` is not subscriptable (i.e. can not be used with `[]`).

The type warning you then saw was because the type checker took you by your word and assumed you were really assigning something of type `dict[str, B]` to `m.dic` (even though you weren't).

And this is *not* allowed, because (as you are correctly told by the type checker) a dictionary is **invariant** in its value type. This is true by default for *all* generic types in Python, as stated in [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance).

In other words, since you declared `.dic` to be of type `dict[str, A]`, you are not allowed to assign `dict[str, B]` to it, even though `B` is a subclass of `A`.

---

### Niche alternative: `TypedDict`

If you *know ahead of time* that only very specific keys will be allowed in your dictionary, you can use the [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) construct.

It doesn't seem like this is what you are going for, since you allow adding keys via a public interface on `MyClass`, but if it were, you would just need to define your dictionary types as well as a corresponding [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) of [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) types to annotate the `name` parameter in your methods. This amounts to a pretty verbose setup, but it works:

```py
from typing import Any, Literal, TypeAlias, TypedDict, Union


class A:
    ...


class B(A):
    def method_B(self) -> Any: ...


class C(A):
    def method_C(self) -> Any: ...


class DicT(TypedDict, total=False):
    A_obj: A
    B_obj: B
    C_obj: C


KeyT: TypeAlias = Literal["A_obj", "B_obj", "C_obj"]


class MyClass:
    dic: DicT = {}

    def add_B_obj(self, name: KeyT) -> None:
        self.dic[name] = B()

    def add_C_obj(self, name: KeyT) -> None:
        self.dic[name] = C()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyClass()
    m.add_B_obj('B_obj')
    m.dic['B_obj'].method_B()
```

This passes `mypy --strict` with no issues.

Note that `total=False` on your `TypedDict` is necessary, since you want to allow any number of the supported keys to be present.

I also used [`TypeAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias) just for better readability here.

---

In conclusion, I would recommend going the `assert` route as mentioned in the beginning. This not only satisfies *some* type checkers (don't know about Pylance), but it also adds an additional sanity check for you. Additional assertions are rarely a bad idea in my opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm writing code that has to be compatible with old version of Python, so `TypedDict` is not a alternative. But the `assert` approach is very appropriate