# Python shelve module type hints in PyCharm, "expected type xx, got Shelf[object] instead"

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, shelve

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting IDE warnings about how I'm using the Python shelve module.  All of the code here functions fine, I'm just getting IDE (PyCharm 2022.2.3 community edition) type warnings that I'd like to clean up.

A super basic test that exemplifies the issue:

```python
import shelve

s = shelve.open("testshelf.db")

s["my_list"]: list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(len(s["my_list"]))
```

Here I get a warning trying to get len(s["my_list"]):

I don't have enough reputation to post images, but the warning highlights s["my_list"] and says:

```
Expected type 'Sized', got 'object' instead
```

I tried to get fancier with it based on another answer on here, but it just moved the issue:

```python
import shelve
from typing import Dict

s = shelve.open("testshelf.db")

s["my_list"]: list = [1, 2, 3, 4]


def foo(s_: Dict[str, list]):
    print(len(s_["my_list"]))


foo(s)
```

Now I get a similar warning highlighting s in foo(s):

```
Expected type 'dict[str, list]', got 'Shelf[object]' instead
```

Again, both examples run fine and produce expected output, I'd just like to get rid of the IDE warnings if possible.  I am still learning about type-hinting and this is my first use of Python shelve.  It seems to be a very convenient and easy-to-use solution to a use case I have, but not if I have to suffer IDE warnings or disable them or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `shelve.open` returns a [`shelve.Shelf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf) instance (specifically a `shelve.DbfilenameShelf`). That is a `MutableMapping` subtype.

A `shelve.Shelf` thus behaves essentially like a regular old `dict`, when it comes to type safety. Since the created `Shelf` can hold essentially any type of object, the inferred type is `shelve.Shelf[Any]`. And all values in a mapping are treated the same by a static type checker. See this related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74074548/type-annotation-for-mutable-dictionary/74079684#74079684) for more insight.

The type checker can't know that a *specific* value has the `__len__` method implemented. It must treat them all as `object`. Not all objects have a concept of size. That is where the warning comes from.

As for solutions, there are a few options. Here are the most practical ones IMHO.

### A) Intermediary variable

The simplest one in my opinion is to use an intermediary variable.

Write like this:

```py
import shelve

s = shelve.open("testshelf.db")
my_list: list[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# do stuff with `my_list`
s["my_list"] = my_list
```

Read like this: (declares the `list` type argument to be `int`)

```py
import shelve
from typing import cast

s = shelve.open("testshelf.db")

my_list = cast(list[int], s["my_list"])
print(len(my_list))
```

Or alternatively like this: (list elements will be inferred as `Any`)

```py
import shelve

s = shelve.open("testshelf.db")

my_list = s["my_list"]
assert isinstance(my_list, list)
print(len(my_list))
```

### B) Declare items as `Sized`

If you know that **all** items in your shelf will implement the `Sized` protocol (i.e. have the `__len__` method), you can cast it as such:

```py
import shelve
from collections.abc import Sized
from typing import cast

s = cast(
    shelve.Shelf[Sized],
    shelve.open("testshelf.db"),
)

s["my_list"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(len(s["my_list"]))
```

Obviously, if you know that all items will be not just "something `Sized`", but specifically lists of integers, you could cast it like this as well. Just use `cast(shelve.Shelf[list[int]], ...)` instead.

### C) Fine-grained structural subtyping

This may be overkill, but if you know that **all** items in your shelf will share a certain protocol (/interface) beyond just `__len__`, you can explicitly define one in advance and the cast it accordingly.

Say for example that all your objects in the shelf will be some generic containers with elements of type `T` and have the `__len__` and `__iter__` methods, as well as a `remove` method. You handle it like so:

```py
import shelve
from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar("T")

class ShelfItem(Protocol[T]):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        ...

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        ...

    def remove(self, element: T) -> None:
        ...

s = cast(
    shelve.Shelf[ShelfItem[int]],
    shelve.open("testshelf.db"),
)
...
```

---

### References

- [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)
- [Collections ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)
- [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)

Comment: Solution A is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.  I tried a couple different approaches to casting with intermediate variables but from your example I just didn't know how to do it correctly in Python.  In my actual application I'm working with lists of dicts, so the actual line looks like: my_list_of_dicts = cast(list[Dict], my_shelf["shelf_key"]), and now PyCharm recognizes it as such.