# How to handle inheritance in mypy

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I'm trying to add mypy to my python project but I have found a roadblock. Let's say I have the following inheritance:

```py
class BaseClass:
    base_attribute: str


class A(BaseClass):
    attribute_for_class_A: str


class B(BaseClass):
    attribute_for_class_B: str
```

Now let's create some code that handle both instances of these classes, but without really knowing it:

```py
@dataclass
class ClassUsingTheOthers:
    fields: Dict[str, BaseClass]

    def get_field(self, field_name: str) -> BaseClass:
        field = self.fields.get(field_name)
        if not field:
            raise ValueError('Not found')
        return field
```

The important bit here is the `get_field` method. Now let's create a function to use the `get_field` method, but that function will require to use a particlar subclass of `BaseClass`, `B`, for instance:

```py
def function_that_needs_an_instance_of_b(instance: B):
    print(instance.attribute_for_class_B)
```

Now if we use all the code together, we can get the following:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_using_the_others = ClassUsingTheOthers(
        fields={
            'name_1': A(),
            'name_2': B()
        }
    )
    function_that_needs_an_instance_of_b(class_using_the_others.get_field('name_2'))
```

Obviously, when I run `mypy` to this [file](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamizbadger/bbc48f7145469a026c1a4fdb7ad1bd86) (in this gist you find all the code), I get the following error, as expected:

```
 error: Argument 1 to "function_that_needs_an_instance_of_b" has incompatible type "BaseClass"; expected "B"  [arg-type]
```

So my question is, how do I fix my code to make this error go away? I cannot change the type hint of the `fields` attribute because I really need to set it that way. Any ideas? Am I missing something? Should I check the type of the field returned?

Comment: You really cannot change this / make this typesafe, neither in python nor in most / all other typed languages. You basically need to ignore the mypy error since *you* know more than mypy in this case. And then you need to be careful to never change the types you put into the dictionary because then you break your manual type contract which you told mypy not to check.

Comment: You probably need to do something that does the *runtime type checking* so the static analysis can narrow the type.

Comment: If you rework `field` into a `typing.TypedDict`, you can save yourself runtime checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot change the type hint of the `fields` attribute

Well, there is your answer. If you declare `fields` to be a dictionary with the values type `BaseClass`, how do you expect any static type checker to know more about it?

(Related: [Type annotation for mutable dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74074548))

The type checker does not distinguish between different values of the dictionary based on any key you provide.

If you knew ahead of time, what the exact key-value-pairs can be, you could either do this with a [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) (as `@dROOOze` suggested) or you could write some ugly [`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal)s with different [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) string values for `field_name` of your `get_field` method.

But none of those apply due to your restriction.

So you are left with either type-narrowing with a runtime assertion (as alluded to by @juanpa.arrivillaga), which I would recommend, or placing a specific `type: ignore[arg-type]` comment (as mentioned by @luk2302) and be done with it.

The former would look like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

class BaseClass:
    base_attribute: str

@dataclass
class A(BaseClass):
    attribute_for_class_A: str

@dataclass
class B(BaseClass):
    attribute_for_class_B: str

@dataclass
class ClassUsingTheOthers:
    fields: dict[str, BaseClass]

    def get_field(self, field_name: str) -> BaseClass:
        field = self.fields.get(field_name)
        if not field:
            raise ValueError('Not found')
        return field

def function_that_needs_an_instance_of_b(instance: B) -> None:
    print(instance.attribute_for_class_B)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class_using_the_others = ClassUsingTheOthers(
        fields={
            'name_1': A(attribute_for_class_A='foo'),
            'name_2': B(attribute_for_class_B='bar'),
        }
    )
    obj = class_using_the_others.get_field('name_2')
    assert isinstance(obj, B)
    function_that_needs_an_instance_of_b(obj)
```

This both keeps `mypy` happy and you sane, if you ever forget, what value you were expecting there.